# C++ Character Frequency Linked List

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

For my project, I need to read in a file and count the times each character appears and store it in a linked list. Below is what I have for the reading in the file portion of the program:

```
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

inFile.open(inputfile.txt);

char ch;

list<charFrequency> charFreqList;
list<charFrequency>::iterator i;

inFile >> ch;
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    charFrequency cf(ch);
    charFreqList.push_back(cf);

    for (i = charFreqList.begin(); i != charFreqList.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (i->getCharacter() == cf.getCharacter())
        {
            i->increment();
            charFreqList.pop_back();
        }
    }

    inFile >> ch;
}

inFile.close();
```

I need the program to go through and if the character is already in the linked list, it just needs to increment the count of the character but only leave one instance of the character in the list, however, I get an error message stating "list iterator not implementable". I know it has to do with the pop_back() as it removes the last element, but I don't know about avoiding this issue.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: A `std::map<char, int>` is a whole lot easier than doing this with a linked list.

Comment: Are you required to use a list? A mapping type is more intuitive and will likely preform better.

Comment: `std::map<char,int> CharMap;...while(!inFile) { inFile >> ch; CharMap[ch]++; }`  That's in essence the solution to both of your issues if you used a map.  A measly 2 line loop.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I HAVE to use a linked list.

Comment: @FreddyRivas - How are you supposed to store a character *and* a count at the same time?  The only way to do this is to store a struct in the linked list that holds a character and a counter, something like a `std::list<std::pair<char, int>>`.  Are you allowed to use this?  If not, please lay out exactly what you are allowed to use, since I don't see it working any other way.

Comment: If you're only allowed to use a linked list, then you have to declare two linked lists, one for characters and one for counts. And your current implementation is not correct.

Comment: The linked list holds a character frequency class that holds the character and frequency of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, only add a `charFrequency` if the character doesn't exist, otherwise you increment the count.  It would also be easier if a new `charFrequency` started with a count of 1.

Second, change your input loop to not check for `eof()`.  This is explained in many threads on SO.

```
class charFrequency
{
   int count;
   char ch;
   public:
       void increment() { ++count; }
       char getCharacter() const { return ch; }
       int getCount() const { return count; }
       charFrequency(char c) : ch(c), count(1) {}
};
```

Last, for kicks, let's use some C++ and use the `std::find_if()` algorithm function instead of writing a loop.  Introduce a function object below that finds a character.

```
struct FindCharacter
{
    char ch;
    FindCharacter(char c) : ch(c) {}
    bool operator()(charFrequency& cf) const
    { return cf.getCharacter() == ch;   }
};
```

So now putting this all together, we have this:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

    //...
    while (ifs)
    {
        ifs >> ch;

        // Search for character 
        std::list<charFrequency>::iterator it = std::find_if(charFreqList.begin(), charFreqList.end(), FindCharacter(ch));

        // if not found, add new charFrequency to list
        if ( it == charFreqList.end())
            charFreqList.push_back(charFrequency(ch));
        else
            it->increment();  // increment
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I got it to work! I had the charFrequency class already created, just didnt post the code for it, but adding the struct and the while loop got it working. I also took your advise on initializing the count at 1 and not 0.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push into the list and remove it back. You could do something like below, or break from the if condition in your code and then remove the last element (not in the loop)

```
list<charFrequency> charFreqList;
list<charFrequency>::iterator i;
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    charFrequency cf(ch);
    Predicate pre(ch); //Write your predicate functor

    //check if the char is present
    i = std::find_if(charFreqList.begin(), charFreqList.end(), pred); 
    if( i != charFreqList.end() )
      i->increment();
    else
      charFreqList.push_back(ch); //insert only when not present

    inFile >> ch;
}
```

However, std::list is a wrong choice of datastructure here, it shall give a bad run time complexity.